# Is it correct to put the adverbial phrase of place at the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

Is it correct to put the adverbial phrase of place at the beginning of a sentence? For example:

> In the center of the city there is a street where there are a lot of shops.

Comment: Yes, it's OK. It involves the preposing of the PP "in the centre of the city".

Comment: Moving the phrases around changes emphasis and focus. So, if a context demands a focus on the city then your sentence is the most likely (for example, in a description of the city).  But if the contextual focus was on finding a street with a lot of shops you might expect: “There is a street with a lot of shops in the centre of the city.”

Answer (score 1):

Your example sentence is perfectly valid. If you wished to rearrange it, "There is a street in the center of the city where there are lots of shops," would also be acceptable. Both versions have the same meaning.

Comment: Also _In the centre of the city is a street ..._: "There" is optional in this construction.